# Getting 'optional error' after updating Xcode 6 beta 6 to beta 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type, beta

I recently updated my Xcode 6 beta 6 to Xcode 6 beta 7 and suddenly portions of my code does not compile. I have this function in my code which gives me the error *Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type* on the line `if let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager`.

```
func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.textHasBeenTapped = true

    if let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView{
        if let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager {
        // rest of code

        }
    }
```

I have tried making textView an optional type like below (which removes the initial error), but it instead gives the error *Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?* on the line `location.x = textView?.textContainerInset.left`. If I insert either `!` or `?` after `left` it instead gives me the error: *Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'CGFloat'* suggesting that I should delete either '!' or '?' thus making a kind of error loop.

```
func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.textHasBeenTapped = true

    if let textView: UITextView? = recognizer.view as? UITextView{
        if let layoutManager = textView?.layoutManager {

            var location: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(textView)
            location.x = textView?.textContainerInset.left
            // rest of code
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original problem actually stems from the fact that UITextView's layoutManager property was changed in beta 7 so that it's not an Optional any more. Therefore it's guaranteed not to be nil, so you don't need the `if let...` check; you can just plain use the value.

Your making textView an Optional just led to a little more confusion down the line; you should leave it as non-Optional.

Here's how I'd write it, with some comments explaining my changes.

```
func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // You didn't need the self bit here.
    textHasBeenTapped = true

    // textView should be non-optional, and you don't need to bother
    // specifying the type, as it can be inferred from the cast.
    if let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView {

        // You don't need if let... here as layoutManager is now non-optional
        let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
        // You don't need to specify the type here, as it can be inferred
        // from the return type of locationInView        
        var location = recognizer.locationInView(textView)
        location.x = textView.textContainerInset.left
        // rest of code
    }    
}
```

---